# Retrieve key of max value in a hash of hases

Tags: ruby

I have a method that is returning a hash setup like this

```
{
  user_id => { date => count, date => count },
  user_id => { date => count, date => count }
}
```

How would I go about ordering this list by the highest count?

**EDIT:** Sorry I wasn't specific, I have a hash of dates and values. I would like to get the highest count for the the most recent month.

```
my_hash = {
  3 => {
    "2013-07-01 00:00:00+00" => 1
  },
  6 => {
    "2013-06-01 00:00:00+00" => 1,
    "2013-07-01 00:00:00+00" => 2
  },
  5 => {
    "2013-06-01 00:00:00+00" => 2,
    "2013-07-01 00:00:00+00" => 5
  }
}
```

Comment: Which count? You have multiple counts in each of the value hashes. And do you mean to sort the top level hash or the value hash?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
hash = {
  1 => { 'a' => 2, 'b' => 4 },
  2 => { 'c' => 6, 'd' => 12 },
  3 => { 'e' => 8, 'f' => 10 }
}

Hash[hash.sort_by { |user_id, date_counts| date_counts.values.max }.reverse!]
#=> {2=>{"c"=>6, "d"=>12}, 3=>{"e"=>8, "f"=>10}, 1=>{"a"=>2, "b"=>4}}
```

**UPDATE**

This extracts the `date`-`count` pairs and sorts them highest to lowest:

```
sorted = my_hash.values.flat_map(&:to_a).sort.reverse
#=> [["2013-07-01 00:00:00+00", 5], ["2013-07-01 00:00:00+00", 2], ["2013-07-01 00:00:00+00", 1], ["2013-06-01 00:00:00+00", 2], ["2013-06-01 00:00:00+00", 1]]
```

The first one is the most recent date with the hightest count:

```
sorted.first[1] # => 5
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much. I'll be sure to ask my questions more thoroughly from here on out.

Answer (score 2):

I think [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#max_by-instance_method) will be a good option for the same:

```
my_hash = {
  3 => {
    "2013-07-01 00:00:00+00" => 1
  },
  6 => {
    "2013-06-01 00:00:00+00" => 1,
    "2013-07-01 00:00:00+00" => 2
  },
  5 => {
    "2013-06-01 00:00:00+00" => 2,
    "2013-07-01 00:00:00+00" => 5
  }
}

my_hash.max_by{|k,v| v.max_by{|k1,v1| [k1,v1]}}
# => [5, {"2013-06-01 00:00:00+00"=>2, "2013-07-01 00:00:00+00"=>5}]
#if you want user  id of highest count for the the most recent month.
my_hash.max_by{|k,v| v.max_by{|k1,v1| [k1,v1]}}.first
# => 5
# highest count for the the most recent month.
my_hash.max_by{|k,v| v.max_by{|k1,v1| [k1,v1]}}[-1].values[-1]
# => 5
```